# Reloading masonry content

Tags: jquery, masonry

I am trying to update the layout of a masonry page when the height of an element is changed. I would like the elements to automatically re-fit like they do if you resize the window. I have tried numerous methods and am now at this which seems to do nothing:

```
function masonryReload() {
                jQuery('#container').masonry('reloadItems');
            }
```

Am I missing something here or is there another method that is better suited to what I want?

If anyone has any experience with this, it would be much appreciated.

---

UPDATES:
JS Function:

```
function masonryReload() {
            jQuery('#container').masonry('reload');
        }
```

HTML:

```
 <li id="logo" style="padding-right: 25px;" onclick="masonryReload();"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/logo.png"></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.masonry('reload')`](http://desandro.github.io/masonry/docs/methods.html#reload)

It's defined in the docs, however simply using `.masonry()` again should do the trick.

---

Following your code. Move away from the inline onclick handler, and put it all inside JS:

**HTML**

```
<li id="logo" style="padding-right: 25px"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/logo.png"></li>
```

**JS**

```
function masonryInit() {
    jQuery("#container").masonry();
    console.log("It works!");
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    masonryInit();
    $("#logo").click(masonryInit());
});
```

Comment: i have literally just found that, given it a go and it's not working. Seems to be the right method though

Comment: @dwinnbrown In that case, post the HTML you use and the JS where you call that function.

Comment: also gave `.masonry('layout')` a shot but nothing

Comment: @dwinnbrown See my previous comment.

Comment: @dwinnbrown Please try again, and if it doesn't work take a look at the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98160/discussion-between-dwinnbrown-and-bram-vanroy).