# Loading Content Dynamically in Masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, layout, masonry

I use masonry to arrange "item" divs into a larger "container" one.
I have a simple php script (refresh.php) that returns a list of div elements, filled from a sql query. Basically:

```
<?php
echo "<div class='item'> xxxx </div>";
echo "<div class='item'> xxxx </div>";
echo "<div class='item'> xxxx </div>";
echo "<div class='item'> xxxx </div>";
?>
```

I want these elements to load on my main html page when I click on a link, so I added this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function updaten() {
      $('#container').load('refresh.php');
   }
</script>
```

I then added a link within the html page to run the script:

```
<a href="#" onClick="updaten()" > Update! </a>
```

Then right below is the rest of the html code with the container div:

```
<div id='container' class='masonry js-masonry' data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 500, "itemSelector": ".item" }'>

</div>
<script src="masonry.pkgd.js"> </script>
<script src="jquery-1.10.1.js"> </script>
</body></html>
```

If I load the page and click on "Update!", the results appear on the page, but the layout is all wrong. There are plenty of vertical gaps between the items, which are of irregular height (but all 500px wide). I can't get a nice, gapless layout (which I do get when I just copy/paste the code generated by the php page into the html source).

I have tried forcing a reload by adding one of these to the updaten() function, but it does not work:

```
$('#container').masonry( 'reloadItems' );
$('#container').masonry( 'layout' );
```

Console tells me that "masonry" is an unknown property or method.

I have tried this too: [Reloading masonry content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34320031/reloading-masonry-content)
but without success.

How can I reload masonry without reloading the page so that my elements are properly ordered?

Comment: How are you initializing masonry the first time?

Comment: shouldn't `<div id='container' class='masonry js-masonry' data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 500, "itemSelector": ".item" }'>` be enough to intialize it?